# How can I convert a Lead automatically setting Lead_Rating to 'Cold' before saving?

Tags: lead-conversion

I want to use a button to quickly convert a lead into a 'Cold' account. Can I call Database.LeadConvert() then open a VisualForce page to edit a couple of Account fields but always set Lead_Rating to Cold then save the converted account?

I thought about using the standard account controller but overriding save(). Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general strategy here is to do the following:

1. Create a custom button on Lead: `Convert to Cold Account`
2. Button is attached to a VF page/controller. Use the page to enter fields that the controller getters will see.
3. Upon `Save`, the Controller then executes a series of DML actions:

**DML actions**

4. Update the Lead record to set `Lead_Rating` to `Cold`. This only has relevance if you map this to some Account/Contact field or ..for historical reporting on converted Leads.
5. use `convertLead(..)` to convert the Lead. SFDC will map Lead fields to Contact/Account. You'll makes sure to not create an Opportunity by using `isDoNotCreateOpportunity(true)`.  `LeadConvertResult.getAccountId()` will let you know the `convertedToAccountId` and you can then update that Account with the properties you collected from the user in step 2.  (Alternatively, you can use custom Lead fields to capture the properties in step 2 and have SFDC Lead mapping place them in the Account.)

Comment: Thanks. This has clarified things for me. I'll make progress and report back.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Marked answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field on the Lead object with value "Cold" and map it

create the field on the lead (use standardvalue or whatever to set the value of Cold).
go to:
Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields > Lead Custom Fields & Relationships >
Press: Map Lead Fields

and map the field to the Lead_Rating field

Comment: I don't want every Lead to be rated 'Cold' but I want to rate some of them programmatically. I would have thought it possible to write a controller extension to update the Account field on Save.

Comment: In the Controller extension, can I not update fields in the record in context? Account ac = (Account)stdController.getRecord(); ac.Lead_Rating__c = 'Cold'; ... save();

Answer (score 0):

You can use can use Database.LeadConvert() wherein you can supply the account id that you want to select. For updating the account you will have to do it as a separate update DML on account.

```
      Database.LeadConvert convLead = new database.LeadConvert();
      convLead .setLeadId(Lea.Id);
      convLead .setAccountId(acc.Id);
      convLead.setConvertedStatus('ClosedConverted');
      convLead .setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);           
      Database.LeadConvertResult[] LeaConvResults = Database.convertLead(leadCollectionArray,false);
```